# Nuxt3 with Firebase Hosting using Cloud Functions: Where to see the other non-hosting cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, nuxtjs3

I have set up my Nuxt app (Nuxt3) to use Firebase Hosting with Cloud Functions. **This works fine and able to deploy**. However, now I wanted to use a cloud function to handle events triggered in Firestore database. I set up a sample "hello world" cloud function by following the Firebase Cloud Functions tutorial , **but now when deploying this new hello world function via the local emulator, the function is no where to be found!**

Here is the Emulator log when I run `firebase emulators:start`:

[image]

I see the function output is the `server` folder, but that is for the app hosting.

**Where is the `helloWorld` cloud function I made?**

Directory structure:

`functions/`:

[image]

And the app's root contains a `firebase.json` like so:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "source": ".output/server",
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ]
  },
  "hosting": [
    {
      "site": "<removed for this post>",
      "public": ".output/public",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "cleanUrls": true,
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "function": "server"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My `helloWorld.js` function is correctly transpiled into the `build` folder:

[image]

Where/how do I access my Hello World function I made? The emulator ONLY seems to show the hosting function.

Comment: Slight hint on terminology: “deploying … via the local emulator”.  Deployment to me, at least, is placing something publicly available (to the cloud). It’s done via the Firebase CLI, but not by the Firebase Emulators.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your post that makes the Firebase Functions Emulator look in the `functions` folder. It gets completely ignored.

You’ve configured it as:

`functions.source: .output/Server`

The default for this field is “functions”. Thus, in many samples, it seems like there would be a special meaning for that folder name. It’s just a default.

Thus: it looks into `.output/Server/index.js` (I think) and executes that.

If you want multiple Functions entry points, have a look at the “codepaces” feature recently released: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions

Note: I haven’t used codespaces myself

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a look and report back.

Comment: I need to delete this question and make a new one as I am totally off track here. Let me start new.